# Flash player disappears on Facebook timeline after loading more feed results (from scrolling down)

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-timeline

I'm developing an application that shares a flash-based music player on people's Facebook profile. On the normal profile (pre-timeline) it works fine. On timeline profiles, the player loads and plays and everyone is happy until you scroll down and the timeline loads more results into the feed. Then the flash player disappears from the page (and stops playing music as well). Note that this only happens when viewing your own profile...when opening the player on someone else's profile (timeline or not), it does not disappear when scrolling.

I've confirmed via the console that the  which loads the player in the iframe on the feed is *disappearing*. The flash player is not in some state of buggy limbo, it's actually gone, taking its markup with it.

Yes, wmode="opaque".

Any ideas on how to preserve a flash player across loading feed results on your own profile in the Facebook timeline?

Comment: I think you should file a bug report with Facebook, and ask them if this maybe is the desired behavior.

Comment: Agree, this should be taken up with Facebook. It happens to YouTube, SoundCloud, and all other embedded players. I think if there was a way to prevent it, one of those bigger sites would have done so.